# echarts 5.0 unreadable tooltip

Tags: echarts

After upgrading to echarts 5.0, my tooltips became unreadable. It looks like the font color went from white to a dark grey which is almost invisible against a dark background. Setting textStyle.color explicitly to white makes no difference.

Is this a regression in echarts, or has the API changed here?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you do it in 5.0 version.

Could you please test the test code?

echarts example link https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        padding: 10,
        textStyle: {
          color: '#fff',
        }, 
    },
    series: [{
        data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
        type: 'line'
    }]
};
```